# Run storm nimbus on AWS EC2 cluster always Failed to get local hostname

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to run storm on my AWS EC2 instances as a cluster. However, I got this error:

`ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.util.ContextUtil@550571f6 - Failed to get local hostname java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx: ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx: Name or service not known`

I also got similar error (java.net.UnknownHostException) when try to run kafka-console-consumer.sh.

What's wrong with this? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide storm config?

Comment: Hi Vor, sorry for late resonse. I have solved it by adding:
`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx`
on my /etc/hosts